# Android bindService or/and startService

Tags: android

I want to create Service using `bindService`  method.
But when I close one Activity my Service is destroyed, and I don't want that.

I try to put service in foreground using  `startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);` service onCreate , but service still destroy.

Now I try with call two methods for starting Service at same time :

```
    Intent bindIntent= new Intent(this, ServiceC.class);
    startService(bindIntent);
    bindService(bindIntent, onService, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

By calling these two methods Service not destroyed. My app work fine with this method.

Can someone explain to me whether this is a good way or if it is not  can you please give me idea why `startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);` does not work ?

What is the best way to use bindService  but at the same time I don't want the service to self destroy.

Comment: I know this is old question, but shamelessly asking got any right solution for using bindService?

Answer (score 8):

I Used the same solution and it's a legitimate one. From [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) ref:

> A service can be both started and have
>   connections bound to it. In such a
>   case, the system will keep the service
>   running as long as either it is
>   started or there are one or more
>   connections to it with the
>   Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag. Once
>   neither of these situations hold, the
>   service's onDestroy() method is called
>   and the service is effectively
>   terminated.

`startForeground()` is not working because it just tries to prevent the service from being killed by the system, but its lifecycle is another thing: if nothing is more bound to that service and it wasn't started, it just stops.

Comment: So you declare there no solution with using bindService? we have to change all our implementation from bindService to startService ?

Answer (score 0):

If you start service with startService() it is not destroyed. Tried starting a service, which extends IntentService and have a loop in onHandleIntent(). When loop is finished, then service destroyed and it is not related with Activity finish. User can close application, but service is not being killed.

```
public class MyService extends IntentService
{
  private static final String serviceName = "MyService ";

  public MyService () {
    super(serviceName);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy()
  {
    Log.v(serviceName, "onDestroy");
    Toast.makeText(this, serviceName+" stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 30*1000;
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                Log.v(serviceName, "Service loop");
                wait(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: @Deepscom - the purpose of an IntentService is to kill itself once onHandleIntent() is completed.  That is by design.